# How did I break this effect? It was different just a minute ago

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm experimenting to make a mosaic background for an assignment, it was working fine, I entered a background color in a smart object then applied a "stained glass" effect with medium sized tiles, etc, as in the image.

For some reason the effect is now being applied only in a circle and not on the entire background, a moment ago I was obtaining a uniform effect and that was more similar to what I need, not sure what parameter or setting I have altered and now I "break" it.

Steps I performed to get here:

1. Added a layer with fill layer -> color then picked a blueish
2. Rasterized the layer (or converted to smart object)
3. From filters gallery I have selected "stained glass"
4. Settings as in the image below

The result is partial. Not sure why it is being applied in a circle as only before it was uniform and looked a lot better than now. Unfortunately I don't have a screen shot of what it looked like, as I didn't think it could go so wrong.

[image]

Comment: Not enough info to know whetr the issue is. But frist thing to check is that you dont have a selection enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have set the foreground colour to the same colour as the colour that the layer has been filled with. That would result in something similar to the example you have shown.

Instead, choose a different foreground colour before you run the filter.

The cell border colour for the Stained Glass filter depends on the foreground colour that you choose. If you choose the foreground colour the same as your fill, then the cell border lines will merge into the fill, leaving only the circular area which the light intensity control reveals as visible. If you don't want the circular lighting effect, you can set the light intensity control to 0.

Here's an example showing the result with a darker colour set as the foreground colour.

[image]

Comment: or a layer mask.. or some sort of color blend...

Comment: wow thanks! I did this on black layer with white below, converted to advanced object and applied the filter, then rasterized and inverted it, I have then added a fill layer, and copied it to the mask; now I can select cell/background colors quickly.